# Minecraft Bukkit Sign Inventory

Tags: minecraft, sign, inventory, bukkit

I am making a bukkit plugin with a sign shop that opens a static inventory and you click to get kits. I have gotten the inventory set up, it opens when the sign is clicked, and the items I want are in there. However, when I click in the inventory, the first if statement returns false. Here is my code:

```
@EventHandler
    public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent e){
        if (e.getInventory() == kitInvent){
            Player player = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();
            player.sendMessage("Kit Shop Opened");

            if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName() == ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Grenadier Kit"){
                e.setCancelled(true);
                player.getInventory().clear();
                Potion potion = new Potion(PotionType.INSTANT_DAMAGE, 1);
                potion.setSplash(true);
                ItemStack grenadeStack = new ItemStack(Material.POTION, 32);


                potion.apply(grenadeStack);
                player.getInventory().addItem(grenadeStack);
            }
        }
    }
```

It can't get past the "if (e.getInventory() == kitInvent)" part because when I comment it out, it sends the message "Kit Shop Opened".

Also, am I doing the next if statement correctly, where it checks the item's title? I was having issues there too, but I didn't know if it was simply because of the previous if statement.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: We need to know what `kitInvent` is and what you do to it. Please update your code.

Comment: kitInvent is the inventory I created to hold the kit objects, which you click to choose. It's able to be opened just fine when the sign says what it's supposed to, but then I have the problem above. I put a single kit in it, which displays fine. This has to be the problem code.

Answer (score 2):

The *opened* inventory will never be truly equal to the inventory "kitInvent" because == checks for other things than the name, items inside.
There are many ways you can check if the inventory is the "same" as kitInvent. ("same" *as in what you are WANTING to do, check if the player is in the right inventory*)

Some ways you can check if the inventory is the one you want is to check if the *inventory name* is the same. Although that is the general check, you can also check items in the inventory and item names– but sticking with the name is good enough. (*Especially if you are using ChatColors, because chests can be renamed!*) Also, for extra checks, use equalsIgnoreCase().

`if(e.getInventory().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(kitInvent.getName()))`

Lastly, a quote taken from [this thread about == vs .equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java) tells you that equals() is the way to go if you only want to check ONE thing, nothing else.

> equals will only compare what it is written to compare, no more, no less.

Wish you luck on getting through your project.

Comment: You realize this question is over 3 years old? The Bukkit API is dying at the same time. The answer is appreciated however.

Comment: Thanks for letting me notice that; was the first question to pop up in what I should answer. Will check next time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if (e.getInventory().equals(kitInvent))` instead of ==. .equals looks for identical values rather than the reference.

As for the next if statement, I also recommend doing .equals, since it's considered bad coding practice to use == when comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `if(e.getInventory().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("the name of the inventory you want to do stuff with"))`  this is going to return true if the name of the inventory is equals to the name of the inventory of the event !